# If a sequence $(f_n)$ converges in $L^2$, then $g'(x)\int_0^x f_n(t)\,dt$ converges in $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

The first: Suppose $g$ is increasing and differentiable on $[0,1]$. For every $f\in L^2(0,1)$ define $f^*(x)$, for $x\in [0,1]$, by:
$$f^*(x)=g'(x)\int_0^x f(t)\,dt .$$
If $f_n\to f$ in $L^2(0,1)$, then prove that $f_n^*\to f^*$ in $L^1(0,1)$.

I started like this: First notice that since $g$ increasing, $g'(x)\geq 0$. Now let $\epsilon>0$. Let 
$$f_n^*(x)=g'(x)\int_0^x f_n(t)\,dt .$$
We need to prove:
$$\int_0^1|f_n^*-f^*|\,dx<\epsilon, $$
provided 
$$\left(\int_0^1 |f_n-f|^2 \,dx\right)^{1/2}<\epsilon_1. $$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1|f_n^*-f^*|\,dx&\leq\int_0^1 g'(x)\int_0^x\left|f_n-f\right|\,dt\,dx\\
&\leq \int_0^1 g'(x)\int_0^1 \left|f_n-f\right|\chi_{\{x\ge t \ge 0\}}(t)\,dt\,dx\\
&\leq \int_0^1 g'(x)\left(\int_0^1 |f_n-f|^2\,dt\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_0^x 1 \,dt\right)^{1/2}\,dx\qquad\text{Holder's}\\
&=\epsilon_1 \int_0^1 \sqrt{x}\,\,g'(x) \,dx
\end{align}
If that was right, then what after?

Comment: Separate them in two questions.

Comment: I think they are kinda related. That's why I posted them together

Comment: They may be related, which means you should link to this question when posting the other. But not put them both in the same question.

Comment: I will separate them. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost done.  Note that $g'(x)$ dominates $\sqrt{x} g'(x)$ on this interval, and the integral of $g'(x)$ is less than or equal to $g(1)-g(0)$.  This doesn't require absolute continuity for $g$.  See [Proposition 22 here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/16/245a-notes-5-differentiation-theorems/).

Comment: Yea I know this proposition for increasing functions. So just need to assume $\epsilon_1<\dfrac{\epsilon}{g(1)-g(0)}$, right?

Comment: Yup. Then you're done.